# PHP Add array items from an inner array loop

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to build an array of cart items that has a mix of a la carte items and package deals. I want to pull the products from the packages and enter the products into my order table. Below is what I have. It pulls the data, but will only add the last record of the inner array (package products) to the outer array. The a la carte items are fine.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, item_id, package
        FROM cart WHERE user_id = $userId";
$result = dbQuery($sql);

$arrCartContent = array();

while ($row = dbFetchAssoc($result)) {
    if ($row['package'] == 1) {

        // Add Product Credits to Company and Order
        $arrProductData = fetchProductDataByPackage($row['item_id']);

        $numItem = count($arrProductData);    
        if ($numItem > 0) {                        
            for ($i = 0; $i < $numItem; $i++) {
                extract($arrProductData[$i]);

                $row['product_id'] = $product_id;
                $row['description'] =  $pack_product_name;
            }
        }

    } else {
        $itemDetails = fetchProductDetails($row['item_id']);

        $row['product_id'] = $row['item_id'];
        $row['description'] = $itemDetails['name'];
    }
    $arrCartContent[] = $row;
}

if(!empty($arrCartContent)) {
    foreach ($arrCartContent as $cartData) {

        $product_id = $cartData['product_id'];
        $description = $cartData['description'];

        $sqlInsert      = "INSERT INTO shop_order_x_product 
                            (order_id, product_id, description)
                         VALUES 
                            ($orderId, $product_id, '$description')";

        $resultInsert = dbQuery($sqlInsert) or die('Cannot add order products: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `extract()`. It's hideously lazy programming, and makes for next-to-impossible debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed it up a bit, your general approach is fine, maybe streamlining it a bit will make this a breeze and prevent you from overwriting the `$row` variable inside the loop:

```
$arrCartContent = array();

while ($row = dbFetchAssoc($result))
{
    if ($row['package'] == 1)
    {    
        // Add Product Credits to Company and Order
        $arrProductData = fetchProductDataByPackage($row['item_id']);
        foreach($arrProductData as $productData)
        {
           $new = array();
           $new['product_id'] = $productData['product_id'];
           $new['description'] = $productData['description'];
           $arrCartContent[] = $new;
        }    
    }
    else
    {
        $itemDetails = fetchProductDetails($row['item_id']);
        $new = array();
        $new['product_id'] = $row['item_id'];
        $new['description'] = $itemDetails['name'];
        $arrCartContent[] = $new;
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw my "$arrCartContent[]" omission right after I sent the original question, but then the last record of the inner array was repeating. Setting new arrays worked like a charm though.

Comment: The basic rule is: Don't re-use variables in the same scope. Variables are cheap, no need to re-use them :)

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the $row array elements with each iteration. Try...

```
if ($row['package'] == 1) {

    // Add Product Credits to Company and Order
    $arrProductData = fetchProductDataByPackage($row['item_id']);

    $numItem = count($arrProductData);    
    if ($numItem > 0) {                        
        for ($i = 0; $i < $numItem; $i++) {
            extract($arrProductData[$i]);

            $row['product_id'] = $product_id;
            $row['description'] =  $pack_product_name;
            $arrCartContent[] = $row;
        }
    }

} else {
    $itemDetails = fetchProductDetails($row['item_id']);

    $row['product_id'] = $row['item_id'];
    $row['description'] = $itemDetails['name'];
    $arrCartContent[] = $row;
}
```